# ARMv8-a GNU assembler error : immediate out of range at operand 3

Tags: assembly, arm64, instruction-set, armv8, immediate-operand

I am having trouble performing logical instructions on the ARMv8-a architecture.

for example, "`and x13, x13, #0x0000CCCC0000CCCC`" or "`and x13, x13, #0x0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A`" results in an immediate out of range error, but "`and x13, x13, #0x5555555555555555`" or "`and x13, x13, #0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD`" does not. In this way, sometimes a range error occurs during a 64-bit immediate and sometimes not.

I looked up the official documentation,
According to https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/An-Introduction-to-the-ARMv8-Instruction-Sets/The-ARMv8-instruction-sets, "Logical instructions generally accept a 32-bit or 64-bit constant, which has some constraints in its encoding." What are these "some constraints" and where can I see them?
I cannot find that constraints.

Comment: `and x13, x13, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD` isn't encodeable, GAS complains about it, as expected because it's not a repeating bit-pattern.  Maybe you meant `and x13, x13, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` (without the trailing `D` and with two fewer `F` characters, so it's a 64-bit constant instead of 76-bit.)

Comment: sorry, it was "'AND  x13, x13, #0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD'".

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD doesn't have all its bits contiguous in the one 64-bit chunk (it's `0b111...01`), but as the linked duplicate explains, the encoding also allows a rotate count.

Comment: Interestingly, `and x13, x13, #0` and `#-1` aren't encodeable.  That's good, they didn't waste coding space on useless immediates: `0` as an operand for bitwise-booleans is either a NOP or a zeroing operation, and `eor x13, x13, x13` or `sub` can still produce a zero with a data-dependency on the input (`std::memory_order_consume`) in one instruction.  And that's so rarely needed it would have been fine to need two instructions for that.